# Adding data dynamically from one json object to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamically-generated

Suppose i have a json object friends as:

```
{
   title: Friends
   link: /friends.json
   description: "My friends"
   people: [
   {
   id: "1",
   name: "Matthew",
   img: "img/matthew.jpg"
   },
   {
   id: "2",
   name:"Matt",
   img: "img/matt.jpg"
   },
   {
   id: "3",
   name: "David",
   img: "img/dav.jpg"
   }
   ]
}
```

This is stored as a file friends.json

Now using javascript/jQuery, i need to create a new object good_friends.json and need to add values (DYNAMICALLY and one-by-one) to it from "people" field of friends.json using the "people.id". How can i do that?

Comment: That JSON is invalid in a couple of ways. The keys need to be in double quotes, as do all other strings (such as `Friends` and `/friends.json`). See http://json.org and jsonlint.com.

Comment: Simply make javascript objects from your JSON strings using JSON.parse and make basic javascript operations on your objects.

Comment: I'm quite new to jQuery and json, so don't have much knowledge about them. I can't seem to think of anything that why i've posted this question. It may be a bit dumb but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much going to need a server-side process if you want to save your changes.

You can load the JSON via `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path/to/friends.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // Here, `data` will be the object resulting from deserializing the JSON
        // Store `data` somewhere useful, perhaps you might have a `friends`
        // variable declared somewhere; if so:
        friends = data;
    },
    error: function() {
       // Handle the error
    }
});
```

To add to the deserialized object, you just modify it in memory:

```
friends.people.push({
    id: String(friends.people.length + 1),
    name: "John",
    img: "img/john.jpg"
});
```

Of course, those values will probably come from input fields or something, e.g.:

```
function addPerson() {
    friends.people.push({
        id: String(friends.people.length + 1),
        name: $("#nameField").val(),
        img: $("#imgField").val()
    });
}
```

Now you have an in-memory copy of your data. To *store* it somewhere, you have to have a server-side process you can post it to. You'd probably serialize it before posting, e.g., via `JSON.stringify` or similar. If your browser doesn't have `JSON.stringify` natively (most modern ones do, some older ones don't), you can use [Crockford's](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Or if this is just for your own use, you could display the stringified result in a text field and the use copy-and-paste to paste it into `friends.json` in a text editor.

Here's a complete example, which shows the JSON in a text area: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/eruqev) | [source](http://jsbin.com/eruqev/edit#html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Name:
    <input type="text" id="nameField">
  </label>
  <br><label>Img:
    <input type="text" id="imgField">
  </label>
  <br><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" disabled>
  <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show JSON" disabled>
  <br><div id="msg">&nbsp;</div>
  <hr>
  <textarea id="showField" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Note that all of our script tags are at the end of the
// document. This lets the page load as quickly as possible
// and means we don't have to worry about whether the elements
// have been created yet (they have, because the scripts are
// below them).

// Put all of our code inside a function so we don't
// create globals
(function($) {
    if (typeof JSON === "undefined") {
        // Load Crockford's json2.js
        // NOTE: You'd want to use your own copy, not a hotlink
        // to his github like this.
        var scr = document.createElement('script');
        scr.src = "https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js";
        document.documentElement.appendChild(scr);
    }

    var friends; // Where our deserialized friends.json will go

    // Focus the first field
    $("#nameField").focus();

    // Load the JSON
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://jsbin.com/ojexuz",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // Here, `data` will be the object resulting from deserializing the JSON
            // Store `data` somewhere useful, perhaps you might have a `friends`
            // variable declared somewhere; if so:
            friends = data;

            // Enable our buttons now that we have data
            $("input[type='button']").prop("disabled", "");
        },
        error: function() {
            // Handle the error
            alert("Error loading friends.json");
        }
    });

    // Handle clicks on the "Add" button
    $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
        var nameField = $("#nameField"),
            imgField  = $("#imgField"),
            name      = $.trim(nameField.val()),
            img       = $.trim(imgField.val());
        if (!name || !img) {
            alert("Please supply both name and image");
            return;
        }
        addPerson(name, img);
        $("#msg").text("Added '" + name + "'");
        nameField.focus();
    });

    // An "add this person" function
    function addPerson(name, img) {
        friends.people.push({
            id:   String(friends.people.length + 1),
            name: name,
            img:  img
        });
    }

    // Handle clicks on the "Show" button
    $("#btnShow").click(function() {
        $("#showField").val(JSON.stringify(friends));
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nicely done, the live copy & code will be very useful for any starter looking up JSON/Ajax examples.

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot of valuable info... However, i needed to create a NEW json object and add values to it. How can i do that?

Comment: @VJ41: You probably don't mean "JSON object." You probably just mean "object." (JSON is a textual notation used for exchanging data; once you're interacting with the data in code, you're no longer using JSON, just objects.) To create an object, you use an [object initializer](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), `{}`, optionally with properties in it. I've used one above in `addPerson`. For instance, `var o = {foo: "bar"};` creates an object with one property, `foo`, whose value is `"bar"`, and assigns that object to the variable `o`.

Comment: I need to send the new data to server for further processing. Will i need json object for that?

Comment: @VJ41: Typically you send data to the server in name/value pairs. For complex, structured data, sending a name/value pair where the value is an object graph serialized to JSON is a great way to go.