# How to push one Javascript object into another Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have one function in which I am iterating across data object which I have fetched from database. In the foreach loop I am trying to create one object(trigger) and pushing it to another variable(Geo) which I will use to put in another variable(triggers). Below is the code-

```
var Geo={};

array.forEach(this.cityData,lang.hitch(this, function(data,i){
    var trigger = {
        type: "Inside",

        event: {
            name: data.Name,
            address:data.Address
        }
    };

    var Location= "Location_"+i;
    Geo.Location=trigger;  // pushing trigger in Geo variable
}));

var triggers = {
    Geo  //using Geo in trigger
};
```

is  `var triggers={Geo};` equivalent to this below code ?

And is my pushing code `Geo.Location=trigger;` correct ?

```
var triggers = {
    Geo: {
        Location_1: trigger1,
        Location_2: trigger2 ...... and so on...
    }
};
```

Comment: hi possibly duplicate of this thread pls check out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078630/adding-data-dynamically-from-one-json-object-to-another

Comment: You question seems to want both objects to be inside eachother, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You code have exactly 0 JSON.

Comment: Yes Oleg....I shouldn't have used word JSON object....as these are only javascript variables with some properties. Thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't tested it but it looks like it does almost the same.
Just one thing:
This should give you an exception:

```
var triggers = {
      Geo  //using Geo in trigger
    };
```

The statement should be

```
 var triggers = {
      'Geo': Geo  //using Geo in trigger
    };
```

otherwise triggers will not have a Geo property.

`Geo.Location=trigger;` is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A property in an object accessed through dot notation (obj.property) is always considered simply as the propoerty name - i.e. variables are not evaluated. You can have dynamic property names by using the bracket notation: obj[property], which convert "property" to a string (resolving the variable value if necessary) and uses that as the actual property name.

So, try changin:

```
Geo.Location
```

to:

```
Geo[Location]
```

**Edit**: I'm not sure what is the expected final result, but if you want to achieve an object as shown in your last code block, the correct syntax should be:

```
triggers.Geo = Geo;
```

again, in consideration of the fact that the "Geo" in the dot notation form is simply the string name of the property, and has no relation to the variable of the same name.

Comment: not true, Geo.Location = x and Geo["Location"] = x does the same, it extends the Geo object with a property named Location. Geo[Location] = x extends the Geo object by an anonymous function returning x (in Chrome and it doesn't work in IE)

Comment: @Ela: i agree about your first affermation (Geo.Location = x and Geo["Location"] = x are equivalent), but i don't see any evidence about the correctness of the second one - Geo[Location] = x will add a property in the object having a name equal to the *value* of the variable Location (in the example by the op, this would cycle as "Location_1", "Location_2" and so on) - i made a quick fiddle to show what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/TtJMn/ . Or maybe i misunderstood what you were meaning?